# How to concatenate cell A2 & B2 in cell C2 then down the column?

Tags: excel, vba

The code below works for specified cells where I combine LastName, FirstName from columns A & B into column C.

How can I get it to repeat for a range of cells where the last row may change?

The following code works for A2 & B2. I want it to repeat for A3 & B3 and so on down the rows with the last row changing as each report comes out.

```vb
Sub ConcatenateStrings()

    Dim StringOne As String
    Dim StringTwo As String
    Dim StringThree As String
    StringOne = Range("A2").Value
    StringTwo = Range("B2").Value
    Range("C2").Value = StringOne & ", " & StringTwo

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("C2:C100").Formula= "=A2&", "&B2"` and then `Range("C2:C100").Value = Range("C2:C100").Value`

Comment: @ScottCraner - just forgot to double up the inner quotes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the last row.
2. Write a formula to concatenate columns B and C.
3. Hard-code the formula results.

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
    With ws.Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
        .Formula = "=A2&"", ""&B2"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```